# WPF window not going to background

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF application, I show a new window in this way, from within a method in the first window's code behind.

```
SecondWindow win = new SecondWindow();
win.Owner = this;
win.Show();
```

Why is it that when the second window is shown, I can't pull the first window to the foreground, where it covers the second window when dragged over top of it?

Comment: If you set the owner to the first window, it should be in the background.

Comment: Is `win.Topmost` set to `false`?

Comment: @SuperOli that property isn't set at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer deep in [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2) on the Window.Owner property:

> An owner window can never cover an owned window.

Looks like this is just the default behavior. This can be confirmed by commenting out the second line: `win.Owner = this;`

Comment: That's what I meant when I said *'If you set the owner to the first window, it should be in the background.'*